# wow scroll animation has extra vertical scroll bar when on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got the page with wow animation effects "bounceInUp". Works perfectly fine when local, but as soon as I upload the file to hosting, it starts showing vertical scroll bar for a split second when effect appears. Did anyone encounter anything like it?

code is pretty standard

```
<div class="photoshoots-trdsec wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5">
  <div class="wow bounceInUp"> <img src="images/lookdesk1.jpg" alt=""> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anything different about your srever and local enviromnents?

Comment: not sure (i'm still learning). I've uploaded that static html into wordpress theme folder for test purposes. If it makes any difference (i don't really think it does)

Comment: Is there a link to url so we may review? If it is wordpress, I would imagine there is some conflict.

Comment: here is a static page  dev.birksun.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/photoshoots.html